Change the background color of a focused TextBox to transparent using Avalonia
I've tried to change the Background color of a focused TextBox to transparent in Avalonia.
The Textbox is in a Templated User Control and I want it to be fully transaparent since it's inside a border.
I've tried using styles and resources (a transparent brush), here's the code of the control
<Styles xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:controls="using:AIVA.CustomComponents"
        >
    
    <Style Selector="TextBox:focus-within">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource TransparentBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource TransparentBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    </Style>
    
    <Design.PreviewWith>
        <Border Background="Aquamarine" Padding="100">
            <StackPanel>
                <controls:CustomInputField LabelText="ID" />
                <controls:CustomInputField/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
        
    </Design.PreviewWith>

    <Style Selector="controls|CustomInputField">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
        <!-- Set Defaults -->
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border
                    Width="350"
                    Height="25"
                    Margin="0,25,0,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    BorderBrush="Black"
                    BorderThickness="0,0,0,2">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock
                            Width="100"
                            Height="26"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            FontFamily="Montserrat"
                            FontSize="18"
                            FontWeight="Medium"
                            Text="{TemplateBinding LabelText}"
                            TextAlignment="Left" />

                        <TextBox
                            x:Name="TextInput"
                            Width="250"
                            Height="26"
                            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                            Background="{DynamicResource TransparentBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="0,0,0,0"
                            FontSize="18"
                            FontWeight="Medium"
                            TextAlignment="Center"
                            Text="{TemplateBinding InputText}"
                            
                            >
                            
                        </TextBox>
                    </StackPanel>

                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Styles>

https://imgur.com/5QLtNeC
(Only the non-focused one keeps the transparent background)
Here are some styles thatI I've also tried
<Style Selector="TextBox.CustomInput">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource TransparentBrush}"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource TransparentBrush}"></Setter>
        
    </Style>
    <Style Selector="TextBox.CustomInput:focus-within">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource TransparentBrush}"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource TransparentBrush}"></Setter>
        
    </Style>

https://i.imgur.com/w8XxUvg.png
(There are 2 TextBoxes in this image)
I did my research and it has something to do with the Avalonia Fluent Theme, but I can't remove that package since some components need that to render correctly.
Any help would come in hand, thanks in advance.

Sorry, I've already fix it, now you may see the Templated User Control

By referring to the Documentation Selector with a pseudoclass doesn't override the default you need to override the TextBox default template
the following code will make what you want to achive
<Style Selector="TextBox:focus-within /template/ Border">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource TransparentBrush}" />
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource TransparentBrush}" />
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"></Setter>              
</Style>

<Style Selector="TextBox:pointerover /template/ Border">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource TransparentBrush}" />
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource TransparentBrush}" />
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"></Setter>
</Style>

